# cron, который запускает php скрипт, не работают SQL запросы

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, cron

У хостинга есть вкладка "задание по расписанию", которая для работы использует cron. Я прописал туда php скрипт, который делает curl запросы и примерно через час должен сохранить полученные данные в базу данных mysql. Перед этим полученные данные сохраняются в текстовый файл. Но sql запросы не работают.
У меня 2 sql запроса: удаление всех записей с id IN (...) и вставка около 400 записей. Но даже с сохранением 10 записями оно не работает.

Данные в файл сохраняет.
Пробовал запустить скрипт не через curl, данные сохраняются.
Пробовал запустить скрипт через curl на маленьком количестве запросов, все работает.

В чем может быть проблема? Как ее можно решить?

Может решение данной проблемы есть, но я его не могу найти(

Comment: Разделите запись на несколько запросов, и покажите как insert выполняете

Comment: "INSERT INTO gibdd_fines (user_id, order, order_id, date, status, message, sum, data) VALUES $ins". Где $ins - строка содержит строки, которые нужно вставить

Comment: А разве это поможет, если на маленьких запросах (на 5 записей) тоже не срабатывает? И причем, если я намерено запускаю через cron допустим через минуту на любое количество запросов, она вносит изменения в бд

Comment: Вы код то покажите, гадать сложно

Comment: небось к базе коннектитесь в начале скрипта, а через час, когда заливать данные собрались, то коннект уже отпал по таймауту. еще какой нить mysql has gone away можно в логах найти (в любом случае, надо логи глянуть)